# How to get Nutch 2.3.1 to work with ElasticSearch 5.3.2?

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I have got ElasticSearch 5.3.2 up and running on Ubuntu 16.04 and would like to use Nutch to crawl websites. I have compiled Nutch 2.3.1 and got it to successfully crawl a site, however when I go to index it into Elastic, I get errors.

Command:

bin/nutch index -all

Output:

[image: nutch-error]

In the /var/logs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log file I get this message:

[image: elasticsearch log file]

Does anyone know what this error means and how to fix this issue? Thx

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Nutch 2.3.1 already works with ES 5.3.2 using the normal ES Java plugin. As far as I know, the current Nutch version has just been [upgraded to ES 2.3.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2234).

However, what you can do is to use the [`indexer-elastic-rest`](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/indexer-elastic-rest) plugin which interacts with ES at the HTTP level using the [Jest 2.0.3](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) library.

All you need to do is to configure all ["elasticsearch rest" properties](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/3628e2fd6974b9bdd98cc80274a35c97e22197dc/conf/nutch-default.xml#L1986-L2056) in the Nutch configuration file.

Comment: Thank @val. I ended up giving up on ES 5.3.2 and installed 1.7.2 and now I have Nutch 2.3.1 crawling and indexing into ES nicely. I'll see if I can get it working with ES 2.3.3.

Comment: Awesome, keep us posted.

Comment: @WonkotheSane I add 'indexer-elastic-rest' in nutch plugin.includes config and add "elasticsearch rest" properties, but after run 'bin/nutch  index -all', got 
No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me
https://github.com/mdigiacomi/indexer-elastic

Comment: The link is broken. Do you have another copy of it?

Comment: For anyone else interested, working link of above module
https://github.com/futureweb/indexer-elastic